# Multi-part identifier issue and pivoting data in two ways on a single table/view

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have created a view in SQL that gives me the following data:

```
+------+--------+--------+------+------+
| Year | Issuer |  PNL   | LgSt | PPNL |
+------+--------+--------+------+------+
| 2017 | a      |  47433 | L    |    1 |
| 2016 | b      | -29250 | S    |    0 |
| 2017 | c      | 211469 | S    |    1 |
| 2016 | d      |   8231 | S    |    1 |
| 2018 | a      |  89679 | S    |    1 |
| 2018 | b      | -34655 | L    |    0 |
| 2017 | b      |  65035 | L    |    1 |
| 2017 | c      | -52719 | L    |    0 |
| 2015 | a      |  11621 | L    |    1 |
+------+--------+--------+------+------+
```

The code for the view is:

```
CREATE VIEW
[Portfolio].[HitRatePretable]
AS
WITH CTE1
AS
(
SELECT DP.Issuer, DP.AssetCategory, SUM (DP.GLPeriod) As [PNL],  
SUM(DP.DeltaExpNet) NetExp, SUM(DP.DeltaExpGross) GrossExp, DP.Date, 
DATEPART (YYYY,DP.date) As [Year]
FROM Portfolio.DailyPortfolio DP 
GROUP BY Issuer,DP.AssetCategory ,DP.Date
)
, 
CTE2
AS
(
SELECT CTE1.Year, CTE1.Issuer, SUM(CTE1.PNL) [PNL], 
CASE 
    WHEN ABS(MAX(CTE1.NetExp)) > ABS(MIN(CTE1.NetExp)) THEN 'L'
    ELSE 'S'
END As [LS]
FROM CTE1
GROUP BY CTE1.Year, CTE1.Issuer
HAVING SUM(CTE1.PNL) >1000
OR SUM(CTE1.PNL)<-1000
)
SELECT CTE2. Year, CTE2.Issuer,CTE2.PNL[PNL],CTE2.LS [LgSt],
CASE
    WHEN CTE2.PNL>0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END As [PPNL]
FROM CTE2
```

I need to create another view from this data that looks like this:

```
+------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+
| LgSt |     2015      | 2015Total  |     2016      | 2016Total  |     2017      | 2017Total  |     2018      | 2018Total  |
+------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+
| L    | Sum of (PPNL) | Count of L | Sum of (PPNL) | Count of L | Sum of (PPNL) | Count of L | Sum of (PPNL) | Count of L |
| S    | Sum of (PPNL) | Count of S | Sum of (PPNL) | Count of S | Sum of (PPNL) | Count of S | Sum of (PPNL) | Count of S |
+------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+
```

Before I even attempted that, I tried to do a simpler pivot that would return the data in this format:

```
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| LgSt |     2015      |     2016      |     2017      |     2018      |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| L    | Sum of (PPNL) | Sum of (PPNL) | Sum of (PPNL) | Sum of (PPNL) |
| S    | Sum of (PPNL) | Sum of (PPNL) | Sum of (PPNL) | Sum of (PPNL) |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

My code for the simpler pivot was:

```
select HR.LgSt, [2015],[2016],[2017],[2018]
from portfolio.HitRatePretable HR
Pivot
(
SUM (PPNL) FOR LgSt IN
( [2015],[2016],[2017],[2018])
) AS pvt
```

This returned the following error:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "HR.LgSt" could not be bound.

My questions are:

1. Why did I get that error?
2. How do I create a view with the Total columns?

Thanks.

Comment: You do NOT want to create a view that references a view. This is a performance time bomb. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: You are pivoting on values in LgSt, so those values become columns in the result set and the LgSt column disappears.  are you saying that sometimes LgSt is a year number and sometimes it is L or S?

Comment: I will alter the first view so that I dont create a view that references another view. I changed the code to Pivot for Year instead of LgSt but still getting  the multi-part identifier error on the very first Select HR.LgSt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `SUM` and Total, I will go with `CASE` in a single query like below.

```
select LgSt, 
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR=2015 THEN PPNL ELSE 0 END) as [2015],
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR=2015 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [2015]Total, 
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR=2016 THEN PPNL ELSE 0 END) as [2016],
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR=2016 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [2016]Total,
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR=2017 THEN PPNL ELSE 0 END) as [2017],
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR=2017 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [2017]Total,
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR=2018 THEN PPNL ELSE 0 END) as [2018],
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR=2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [2018]Total
from portfolio.HitRatePretable HR
Group by LgSt
```

Comment: thanks. this works. i did think about doing this but was wondering if using the pivot command would make it more efficient

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep actually conditional aggregation has been demonstrated many times to be slightly (and I mean **very** slightly) faster than using a pivot. The big plus is the syntax is far less obtuse. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select pvt.LgSt, [2015],[2016],[2017],[2018]
from portfolio.HitRatePretable HR
Pivot
(
SUM (PPNL) FOR Year IN
( [2015],[2016],[2017],[2018])
) AS pvt
```

You want to pivot on Year, not LgSt

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the multi-part identifier error.  It's for HR.LgSt

Comment: OOh right,  change HR to pvt.  you are selecting from the result of the Pivot, not the source table.

Comment: thanks. it doesn't get me to the table I want to see but at least the pivot works!